# Convert SQL statement to Linq - tools not working

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc, linq

My SQL works;

```
select Question, QuestionOption.QuestionOption, Response.Answer from Questions
left join QuestionOption on (QuestionOption.QuestionId = QuestionS.Id)
left join Response on (Questions.Id = Response.QuestionId) 
Where PageNumber = 1 AND (Response.UserId = '6c61c415-1e09-4c16-82bf-fbc1b30e3c5a')
```

The PageNumber and Response.UserId are variables which I can grab from my model, but none of the Linq statements I have tried work but I am not sure if it is my Linq or my ViewModel;

```
public class GetQuestionViewModel
{
    public virtual List<Question> Questions { get; set; }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int PageNumber { get; set; }
    public string Question1 { get; set; }
    public int QuestionTypeId { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> LinkedTo { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> Options { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> QuestionRanking { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<QuestionOption> QuestionOptions { get; set; }
    public virtual QuestionType QuestionType { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Response> Responses { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<AspNetUser> AspNetUsers { get; set; }
}
```

I just added the ***public virtual List Questions*** line to my ViewModel, but it still won't compile.

I am not sure I need the AspNetUsers in my model as I am grabbing it in my view in a hidden field using ***@User.Identity.GetUserId()*** but I added it as my View breaks when I point it to the GetQuestionViewModel. Could someone post an example of how this should be done correctly, or recommend a tool that will do this for me? Linqer does not work and I am waiting for Support to come back with a solution.

I know this is way off as it is not even producing the right questions on the PageNumber and I removed all the references to Response as I can't even get this working;

```
    //    var question = from q in db.Questions
    //                   where q.PageNumber == pageId
    //                   orderby q.Ranking
    //                   select new Template.Models.GetQuestionViewModel( )
    //                  { questionId = q.QuestionId,
    //                    questionType = q.QuestionType,
    //                    question1 = q.Question1 };
    //    return View(question.AsEnumerable());
```

Comment: Show the Linq you have tried.

Answer (score 0):

The `DefaultIfEmpty` will turn it from an inner join to a left join

```
var query = from q in db.Questions
            from qo in q.QuestionOptions.DefaultIfEmpty()
            from r in q.Responses.DefaultIfEmpty()
            where q.PageNumber == 1 && r.UserId == '6c61c415-1e09-4c16-82bf-fbc1b30e3c5a'
            select new Template.Models.GetQuestionViewModel( )
            { 
              questionId = q.QuestionId,
              questionType = q.QuestionType,
              question1 = q.Question1 
            };
```

Comment: I tried your query, but it won't compile on "Question" saying the pattern 'Select Many' not found. So I added a line to my ViewModel, but is my syntax wrong? Should it be an ICollection rather than list?